# Can the Lua part of LuaTeX know about tokens?

Tags: luatex

Using `\directlua` and `tex.print`, it is possible to send strings of characters back and forth between TeX and Lua. Let's take an example: starting with a macro `\A`, I pass its replacement text to Lua and back, defining `\B`

```
\edef\A{ab\string c}
\directlua{tex.print("\noexpand\\def\noexpand\\B{\unexpanded\expandafter{\A}}")}
\show\A
\show\B
\ifx\A\B
  \message{Identical :)!}
\else
  \message{Different :(.}
\fi
\bye
```

The two macros appear identical, but they aren't: the weird/special combination of category codes (letter and other) is lost before reaching Lua, and tokenization on the return trip is done using the category code régime in effect when `\directlua` is performed.

Can the `\directlua` line be replaced by some other Lua code which would be able to define `\B` to be identical to `\A`, including category codes? Of course,

```
\directlua{\unexpanded{tex.print("\\edef\\B{\\unexpanded\\expandafter{\\A}}")}}
```

would work (by delaying the expansion of `\A` until after the passage through LuaTeX), but my goal would be to perform some complicated operations on the token lists on the Lua side.

Comment: When you say 'category codes have been lost', I think it would be more accurate to say 'tokenization takes place using the catcode régime applicable when `\directlua` is executed'. (The tokens still have category codes, just not the ones you expected!)

Comment: @Joseph Thanks, I clarified that (and changed `\A` a little, hopefully that makes things clearer). Btw, the French word is régime (we also had that typo in the LaTeX3 doc at some point).

Comment: Drat - edited :-)

Comment: The answer(s) below only handle passing tokens from Lua to TeX (tprint), not passing tokens from TeX to Lua. I wrote an answer in [luatex - How can I get the value of a token list (tl) variable in Lua? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620965/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-token-list-tl-variable-in-lua), but there are some other uses cases (perhaps something can be built with `runtoks()` / [coroutines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20893/) to run TeX from Lua / `scan_*` functions. There's also `put_token`.

Comment: Actually I think `scan_toks` can do as well, there's roughly one answer on the site that use it so far and documentation isn't great, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/555222/250119, pair with expandafter and some other and can read value of token list as well. Print table of token objects from Lua to TeX is easy

Answer (score 18):

You can play with `tex.print()` and catcode tables. The result of

```
tex.tprint({"\\def\\B{ab"},{-2,"c"},{"}"})
```

gives "Identical :)". This is, because -2 is a predefined catcode table where all characters have the catcode "other" (12) except for space (10) assigned. So you get the same as your edef in TeX.

Comment: What is the difference between `tex.print` and `tex.tprint`? And how general is that? It seems that I would need one catcode table for each category code; not much simpler than the TeX way of building arbitrary token lists.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch the difference between the two functions is that `tex.tprint()` can output many strings with different catcode tables with one function call, while with `tex.print()` you need one for each different cc table. You can define catcode tables in advance with the catcodes you want to have, there are a few predefined ones. -- I guess it all depends on what you want to do. I don't understand your question about how general this is.

Comment: well, in my example I only have characters with either the normal catcode régime (`a` and `b` are letters, if I had put `#`, it would be a macro parameter) and the "-2" table (where all characters have catcode other, here only used for `c`). The general question would be how to build a token list with arbitrary combinations of character and category code. I do that in `l3regex`, and doing it in TeX is slightly tricky.

Comment: Actually, your answer only addresses half of the problem: going from Lua to TeX and getting tokens with various catcodes. The other direction seems tougher: if I have a list of tokens in TeX, how can I transmit information about all the catcodes to Lua? I could analyse the token list on the TeX side, and transmit info about each token, but that ends up mixing TeX and Lua in ugly ways I believe.

Comment: If the characters of both (normal catcode régime and the "other" catcodes) don't overlap, you can just define your own catcodes and store them in a catcodetable (with a number n). Then you can use `tex.print(n, "string")` and it will use your predefined cctable.

Comment: I'm doing that in a very general context, with user input, so I can't afford to assume anything about the token list that users are manipulating. For all I know, they may want to build a token list consisting of 11 consecutive `a` tokens with all possible catcodes (1,2,3,4,6,7,8,10,11,12,13). Unlikely of course :).

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch your question is getting harder and harder. You could predefine 13 catcode tables and use these with `tex.print()`. The tex-Lua way might be possible with the token library. But I guess I have to give up at this point and make way for the experts.

Answer (score 10):

Using the `token_filter` callback and the `token` library (as Patrick kindly mentionned to me in comments to his answer) allows to build arbitrary token lists and insert them in the input stream.  The callback should only be called once, it disables itself with `callback.register(..., nil)`.

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\B\expandafter{%
  \directlua
    {
      callback.register
        (
          'token_filter',
          function()
              callback.register ('token_filter', nil)
              return
                {
                  token.create(\number`\a, 11),
                  token.create(\number`\b, 11),
                  token.create(\number`\c, 12)
                }
          end
        )
    }%
  }
\show\B
\def\test#1#2#3{\show#1\show#2\show#3}
\expandafter\test\B
```

This answer only covers the Lua to TeX part.  It should be possible to use `token.expand()` to do the TeX to Lua step, but I don't know how.

Comment: Apparently, `token.expand()` is [broken](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65724/2707).  I will try to update this answer when it is fixed.

Comment: Also looks like that token_filter is removed long ago.

Comment: Talk about `token.expand` see also this related question [luatex - Token expansion with the token library - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65715/token-expansion-with-the-token-library).

Answer (score 7):

A quick summary/"cheat sheet" of the relevant commands (answer the question in title).

- TeX (convenience function): with \usepackage{luacode} it's possible to use \begin{luacode*} ... \end{luacode*} to write Lua code without worrying about catcode.
- Lua built-in has `inspect()` function used to print out some basic
  information about any (userdata) object / pretty-print tables etc..
- Tokens in Lua:

  - To get token from Lua: (see documentation for more details)

    - `token.scan_toks()`: get an argument (`\toks0={...}`-style, **must be wrapped in braces**, drop outermost
      brace, can contain control sequences not in the hash table).
    - `token.scan_toks(false, true)`: get an argument (`\expanded{...}`-style, **must be wrapped in braces**)
    - `token.create("<control sequence name>")`, `token.create(int charcode, int catcode)`

      **Note**

      - create the [impossible control sequence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335994/obtaining-the-name-of-an-undefined-control-sequence-in-luatex#comment824336_335994) if it's not in the hash table
      - the null control sequence (control sequence name = `""`) cannot be created this way
    - `token.get_next()` returns the next token in the input stream, [**must** be in the hash table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335994/250119) <sup>(*1)</sup>
    - `token.new`: (presumably) create a "new" (frozen) token with a definite meaning. There's an example usage at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498118/250119
  - Token format:

    - check **.csname**

      - if is nil: *explicit* character (except some special cases)

        - **.mode** = charcode ([might be **.index** instead in newer versions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646457/how-to-implement-token-get-char?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1610818_646463))
        - **.cmdname** ∈ (left_brace right_brace math_shift
          tab_mark mac_param sup_mark sub_mark spacer letter other_char).

          - if it's not in this list, it could be some internal tokens such as the `\endlocalcontrol` inserted inside a `tex.runtoks()`, which has **.mode** = 10 and **.cmdname** = `extension`, but **.csname** nil
      - else:

        - if **.active**: active character (charcode is in **.csname**, not **.mode**), else: control sequence
        - if .csname is the exact string "\csname\endcsname" (unusually include the backslashes, and regardless of actual value of escapechar) and **.tok** = 0x20000000: is null control sequence token
        - if (...) there are many [internal tokens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/609423/250119), if you want to be very careful, as the LuaTeX manual stated, create a token and get its **.tok** value.
        - else: is the active character/control sequence with the given csname.
        - check **.cmdname** for its *meaning*, can be one of the following

          ```
          token.commands() = {
           [0]="relax",
           "left_brace",
           "right_brace",
           "math_shift",
           "tab_mark",
           "car_ret",
           "mac_param",
           "sup_mark",
           "sub_mark",
           "endv",
           "spacer",
           "letter",
           "other_char",
           "par_end",
           "stop",
           "delim_num",
           "char_num",
           "math_char_num",
           "mark",
           "node",
           "xray",
           "make_box",
           "hmove",
           "vmove",
           "un_hbox",
           "un_vbox",
           "remove_item",
           "hskip",
           "vskip",
           "mskip",
           "kern",
           "mkern",
           "leader_ship",
           "halign",
           "valign",
           "no_align",
           "vrule",
           "hrule",
           "novrule",
           "nohrule",
           "insert",
           "vadjust",
           "ignore_spaces",
           "after_assignment",
           "after_group",
           "break_penalty",
           "start_par",
           "ital_corr",
           "accent",
           "math_accent",
           "discretionary",
           "eq_no",
           "left_right",
           "math_comp",
           "limit_switch",
           "above",
           "math_style",
           "math_choice",
           "non_script",
           "vcenter",
           "case_shift",
           "message",
           "normal",
           "extension",
           "option",
           "lua_function_call",
           "lua_bytecode_call",
           "lua_call",
           "in_stream",
           "begin_group",
           "end_group",
           "omit",
           "ex_space",
           "boundary",
           "radical",
           "super_sub_script",
           "no_super_sub_script",
           "math_shift_cs",
           "end_cs_name",
           "char_ghost",
           "assign_local_box",
           "char_given",
           "math_given",
           "xmath_given",
           "last_item",
           "toks_register",
           "assign_toks",
           "assign_int",
           "assign_attr",
           "assign_dimen",
           "assign_glue",
           "assign_mu_glue",
           "assign_font_dimen",
           "assign_font_int",
           "assign_hang_indent",
           "set_aux",
           "set_prev_graf",
           "set_page_dimen",
           "set_page_int",
           "set_box_dimen",
           "set_tex_shape",
           "set_etex_shape",
           "def_char_code",
           "def_del_code",
           "extdef_math_code",
           "extdef_del_code",
           "def_family",
           "set_math_param",
           "set_font",
           "def_font",
           "register",
           "assign_box_direction",
           "assign_box_dir",
           "assign_direction",
           "assign_dir",
           "combinetoks",
           "advance",
           "multiply",
           "divide",
           "prefix",
           "let",
           "shorthand_def",
           "def_lua_call",
           "read_to_cs",
           "def",
           "set_box",
           "hyph_data",
           "set_interaction",
           "letterspace_font",
           "expand_font",
           "copy_font",
           "set_font_id",
           "undefined_cs",
           "expand_after",
           "no_expand",
           "input",
           "lua_expandable_call",
           "lua_local_call",
           "if_test",
           "fi_or_else",
           "cs_name",
           "convert",
           "variable",
           "feedback",
           "the",
           "top_bot_mark",
           "call",
           "long_call",
           "outer_call",
           "long_outer_call",
           "end_template",
           "dont_expand",
           "glue_ref",
           "shape_ref",
           "box_ref",
           "data",
          }
          ```

          (call long_call outer_call long_outer_call) are user-defined macro.

          In this case **.mode** (or **.index**) will have some cmdname-specific meaning.
  - To send back tokens from Lua to TeX:

    - `tex.print(...)`: (with "trailing newline" i.e. on a separate line)

      - `(token1)`
      - `{ token1, token2 }`
      - `(string content)`
      - `(int catcodetablenumber, string content)`

        (`catcodetablenumber` special values: -1 is current, -2 is
        detokenized)
      - `([int catcodetablenumber], {string1, string2, ...})`
    - `tex.sprint`: same as above but without "trailing newline"
    - `tex.tprint`: shortcut

      ```
      tex.tprint(
          {int catcodetablenumber1, string content1},
          {int catcodetablenumber2, string content2},
          ...
      )
      ```
    - `tex.cprint(int catcode, string content)`
    - `token.put_next( token1, token2 )`, `token.put_next{ token1, token2 }`

      **Note**: you usually don't mix `token.put_next` and `tex.print` (print always come before all put_next!)
- Execute TeX code in Lua:

  - coroutines: print tokens to TeX and return control to TeX [Concurrently interleaving execution of Lua and TeX in LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20893/250119)
  - `tex.runtoks(function() tex.print(...) end)`: run the content
    immediately (dangerous! Do not change TeX mode inside the function)
- Execute Lua code in TeX:

  - \directlua{lua code to be executed... (fully expanded similar to `\message` or `\expanded`, `#` are doubled)}
  - Pass argument in with \luaescapestring{content... (fully expanded similar to `\message` or `\expanded`, `#` are not doubled)}
  - Or leave the argument in the input stream and let Lua pick them up with
    e.g. `token.scan_toks` or `token.get_next` etc.

---

<sup>(*1)</sup>: otherwise it becomes `\IMPOSSIBLE`. A simple `\futurelet` can be used here safely, but there's certain overhead. Use `scan_toks()` if possible.

---

E.g. Lua function to increment the char code of each token by 1, works
across all group levels and takes one expansion step. (demo for "take token list and do complex manipulation")

```lua
function f()
    local tokens=token.scan_toks()
    for i=1,#tokens do
        if tokens[i].cmdname=="letter" then
            tokens[i]=token.create(tokens[i].mode+1, 11)
        end
    end
    tokens[#tokens+1]=token.create(string.byte("}"), 2)
    token.put_next{
        token.create("pretty:n"),
        token.create(string.byte("{"), 1),
        table.unpack(tokens)
    }
end


\directlua{f()}{ab{c}123}  % eventually expand to bc{d}123
```

Another examples: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/555222/250119

Comment: NOTE do not nest tex.print too much, see (my question) [luatex - How can I make macros called from tex.print tail-recursive? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640922/how-can-i-make-macros-called-from-tex-print-tail-recursive/640959#640959)