# Token expansion with the token library

Tags: luatex

I don't understand how the `token` library of luatex works.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}

\def\mymacro{A}

\directlua{%
  t = token.create ('mymacro')
  token.expand(t)
  token.get_next()
}

\end{document}
```

The token.expand does not work as I expected: `luatex` says `Undefined control sequence`. Why?

With the `token.get_next()`, I don't know exactly what I should get...

Comment: Alternatives including using Lua coroutine to pass control to TeX and `tex.runtoks`. See [expansion - Concurrently interleaving execution of Lua and TeX in LuaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20893/concurrently-interleaving-execution-of-lua-and-tex-in-luatex)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately `token.expand` is currently broken.  See the [bug report](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=671) which derives from an example exactly like yours.

Comment: Update: The bug report says "closed" but the asker's code still raises the same error.

Comment: @user202729 Then it would be good for you to report it as a bug.  Note that it was closed several years ago, so a recent change may have broken this again.

Comment: @user202729 The token library got completely replaced, so just because it was not intended in the old library does not mean that it's not intended behavior now. Since the only documentation for `token.expand` is: "The token.expand function will trigger expansion but what happens really depends on what you’re doing where." it's arguably doing exactly what's documented :P I don't know what the old `token.expand` did, but the current one doesn't even take an argument. It expands what's already in the input stream.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Indeed further down the bug report it says "the old token interface is soon obsolete so there will be no more changes to it".

Answer (score 3):

`token.expand` is never useful, and is not fixed even 10 years passed, since every API from luatex is isolated from variables like `cur_cmd`.
But you can write you own `expand`

```lua
%!TEX program=lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\directlua{
local exp_after = token.create('expandafter')
local lbrace = token.create(string.byte('{'))
local rbrace = token.create(string.byte('}'))
function expand()
  token.put_next(lbrace, exp_after, rbrace)
  token.scan_toks(false, true)
end
}
\begin{document}

\def\mymacro{ABC}%

\directlua{
  local t = token.create'mymacro'
  token.put_next(t)
  expand()
  token.get_next()
}

\end{document}
```

If you need take care of the catcodes of braces and redefinition of `\expandafter`,
the code is much longer.

```lua
local lbrace = token.new(string.byte'{', 1)
local rbrace = token.new(string.byte'}', 2)

function expand()
  local cur_exp_after = token.create('expandafter')
  local cur_let = token.create('let')
  local prefix = '^'..'^@'
  while token.is_defined(prefix..'expandafter') or token.is_defined(prefix..'let') do
    prefix = prefix..'^'..'^@'
  end
  local undefined = token.create(prefix..'expandafter')

  tex.enableprimitives(prefix, {'expandafter', 'let'})
  local exp_after, let = token.create(prefix..'expandafter'), token.create(prefix..'let')
  token.put_next(lbrace, exp_after, rbrace)
  token.scan_toks(false, true)
  tex.runtoks(function()
    token.put_next(let, exp_after, undefined, let, let, undefined)
  end)
end
```

Comment: So... what does the code inside this answer do exactly...?

Comment: @user202729 `token.scan_toks(false, true)` scans a fully expanded `<general text>`. The code is essentially the first expansion of `\expanded{\expandafter}\mymacro`.

Comment: Okay I see. With the `expandafter` the net result will be that the following tokens in the input stream will be expanded exactly once. (so e.g. before the `expand()` call, the following tokens in the input stream are `\mymacro \par \end{document}`; after the `expand()` call, the following tokens will be `ABC \par \end{document}` (space characters are only for illustration) Not sure if that's what `token.expand()` is meant to do (since it's broken), but alright.

Comment: Side note, it would be more robust to specify the catcode for the `{` and `}` tokens explicitly.

Comment: @user202729 Thank you! Now I've change it a little to treat their catcodes carefully.

Comment: I didn't expect to handle undefined meaning of `\expandafter` though, but sure it works. // didn't test but the second code feels a bit weird • token.create cannot be used for tokens not in the hash table so you need to enableprimitive before...? • the `cur_*` tokens defined initially is undefined • I'm not sure if that `^^@` will be interpreted as-intended from Lua side, maybe `string.char(0)`?

Comment: @user202729  It is literally `^^@`. Once a token is added to the hash table, it is never removed, so `token.create` always returns a valid token. But after `\let\expandafter\relax`, `token.create'expandafter'` gets a token meaning `\relax`.

Comment: Okay, I think the unexpected part here is that `undefined` is the permanently undefined token (relies on `token.create` returns that token instead of the "expected" token when it's not in the hash table); nevertheless if the token `\^^@expandafter` is previously in the hash table but undefined, then after the function is called `\^^@expandafter`'s meaning will remain `\expandafter` instead of `undefined`. (just for academic purposes. Obviously normally assuming `\expandafter` is the built-in should be is sufficient)

Comment: @user202729 `\expandafter`'s meaning is never changed. `\^^@expandafter`'s state is changed as "not in the hash table" -> "primitive `\expandafter`" -> entry in hash table pointing to a eqtb item meaning "undfined control sequence".

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively it could be implemented with `tex.runtoks` like this

```
tex.runtoks(function()
    tex.sprint {token.create "expandafter"}
end)
```

This relies on some implementation details of LuaTeX however.

Explanation: `tex.runtoks` takes a function that prints out some tokens to be executed immediately; internally it's done by putting `⟨the tokens⟩ ⟨internal \endlocalcontrol token⟩` in front of the input stream, executing a "local run".

So the input stream would have the format

```
\expandafter ⟨\endlocalcontrol⟩ ⟨tokens in the input stream⟩
```

First `\expandafter` is expanded which expands the tokens. Then `⟨\endlocalcontrol⟩` is executed which exits `tex.runtoks`.

Note that the token represented by `⟨\endlocalcontrol⟩` is an internal token which might show up as `BAD` depends on the circumstances. It has the same meaning as the normal `\endlocalcontrol` token however.