# Obtaining the name of an undefined control sequence in LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, lua, token-lists

I want to implement something similar to `\detokenize` as a Lua function. But there is one case where I am prevented from accomplishing my goal.

```
\directlua{tex.sprint("[" .. token.get_next().csname .. "]")}\par
\directlua{tex.sprint("[" .. token.get_next().csname .. "]")}\UNDEFINED
```

The first line above outputs `[par]` and the other outputs `[]`. Replacing `token.get_next().csname` by `token.scan_csname()` doesn't help. How do I obtain the name of an undefined control sequence in LuaTeX?

Comment: good question, I'd have expected .csname or scan_csname to work, but as you say, they don't. Might be better to ask on the luatex list, see what Hans says!

Comment: Reading the  LuaTeX manual I suspect this is 'by design' behaviour, as it's not actually the user input that `token.get_next().csname` returns, rather the csname linked to this input _where it exists_.

Comment: raised on luatex list as http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2016-October/006257.html

Comment: BTW, I suspect a  `\detokenize` equivalent won't work as you can't ell if a token was an active char (due to dropping of the escape char): `~` and `\~` yield the same from `token.get_next().csname`, for example.

Comment: @JosephWright: `\directlua{tex.sprint(token.get_next().active and "active character" or "control sequence")}`

Comment: But wait, there's more: `token.create("UNDEFINED").csname` is empty, while `token.create("par").csname` is `"par"`.

Answer (score 5):

Note that you don't get an empty string because `\UNDEFINED` is not defined but because it has never been scanned by TeX (so there is no internal token of that name)

this plain luatex

```
\long\def\z#1{%
\directlua{texio.write_nl("[" .. token.scan_csname() .. "]")}#1%
\directlua{texio.write_nl("[" .. token.get_next().csname .. "]")}#1%
}

\z\par
\z\UNDEFINED

\bye
```

produces a log

```
[par]
[par]
[UNDEFINED]
[UNDEFINED]
```

showing that just having `\UNDEFINED` being seen by TeX's `#1` argument scanner is enough to get the behaviour you expected.

Comment: It's a bug, then?

Comment: @user114332 no by design (not a design I'd have used myself, especially for `.scan_csname` which could return the string that it scanned, it's more reasonable for `get_next()` as there is no token defined for `\UNDEFINED` until TeX has scanned it. see the email list discussion

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to get is to use the `expand` capability of `scan_toks()` to expand/execute some following tokens, similar to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/649627/250119).

In the example below,

- function `f` does a simple `token.get_next()` (which does not handle the case the following token is not in the hash table)
- function `g` uses `scan_toks(false, true)` to expand the input, and `\immediateassignment` combined with `\futurelet` to force TeX to tokenize the next token.
- function `h` uses [coroutine trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20893/250119) <sub>(although instead of a coroutine, auxiliary functions are used)</sub> to call the `\futurelet` instead. `\immediateassignment` can be added if it needs to work in an expansion-only context; nevertheless in an o-expansion context it will still fail to work.

```tex
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\use_none:n {\__unused}  % put the token \__unused into the hash table
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__h_aux { \directlua{h_aux()} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
print("\n\n\n\n")

function f()
    print("f: csname =", token.get_next().csname)
end

function g()
    token.put_next {
        token.create(string.byte "{", 1),
        token.create "immediateassignment",
        token.create "futurelet",
        token.create "__unused",
        token.create(string.byte "}", 2),
    }
    token.scan_toks(false, true)
    print("g: csname =", token.get_next().csname)
end

function h()
    tex.sprint {
        token.create "futurelet",
        token.create "__unused",
        token.create "__h_aux",
    }
end

function h_aux()
    print("h: csname =", token.get_next().csname)
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode*}


% normal behavior: tokens never seen before (not in the hash table) results in empty csname
\directlua{f()}\par
\directlua{f()}\undefined
\directlua{f()}\undefineda
\directlua{f()}\undefineda
\directlua{f()}\undefinedb

% use function g instead
\directlua{g()}\par
\directlua{g()}\undefined
\directlua{g()}\undefineda
\directlua{g()}\undefineda

% just checking, undefinedb is still not in the hash table
\directlua{f()}\undefinedb

% use function h instead
\directlua{h()}\par
\directlua{h()}\undefined
\directlua{h()}\undefinedb
\directlua{h()}\undefinedb

\begin{luacode*}
print("\n\n\n\n")
\end{luacode*}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The output is

```
f: csname =     par
f: csname =     undefined
f: csname =
f: csname =
f: csname =
g: csname =     par
g: csname =     undefined
g: csname =     undefineda
g: csname =     undefineda
f: csname =
h: csname =     par
h: csname =     undefined
h: csname =     undefinedb
h: csname =     undefinedb
```

You can see that function `g()` and `h()` gets the csname correctly, being `\undefineda` and `\undefinedb`.

Comment: As far as I know futurelet is the safest way instead of e.g. applying `\noexpand` on it then expand it once, which might make it lose the noexpand property (although I'm not sure whether futurelet does the same -- or whether noexpand-ness is preserved by get_token() either)