# Backslashes in macros defined in lua code

Tags: luatex

TeX file:

```
\directlua{require "foo"}
\show\foo
\bye
```

and the contents of `foo.lua`:

```
token.set_macro("foo","\\a\\b\\u\\z")
```

Here is the result:

```
> \foo=macro:
->BADa\b \u BADz.
l.2 \show\foo
```

Why do some backslashes turn into `BAD` while others work like expected?

I think it might be a bug, but ask here first in case I have a fundamental misunderstanding.

Comment: You get BAD as `\a` is not defined in plain, while `\b` is. If you add `\def\a{blub}` it changes. This looks like a bug to me (and I have no idea how to get \\ working).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Actually the requirement is slightly weaker: The command sequences do not have to be defined, but they must have appeared at some point. E.g. adding `\def\gobble#1{}\gobble{\a\z}` would "fix" it too. That's basically what the LuaTeX manual is talking about in "10.6.6 Nota bene".

Comment: @MarcelKrüger yes, I got this. But what about commands like `\\ ` or `\!`? Whatever I do they end up as `BAD!`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It seems like the parser has a problem with non-letter control sequences.

Comment: Related question (regarding how control sequences not in the hash table has surprising behavior: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335994/250119)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The token library pokes into tex internals with almost no checks.

if you do

```
\def\wibble{\a\z}

\directlua{require "foo"}
\show\foo
\bye
```

then you get

```
> \foo=macro:
->\a \b \u \z .
```

But if `\a` hasn't been seen by tex at all there is no hash table entry related to `\a` and nothing to set as the token in the replacement text for `\foo`

Comment: What can one do if one want `\\ ` in the token list? In latex it is defined, but it still gives BAD when used in the set_macro argument.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Specifying `luatexbase.registernumber("CatcodeTableOther")` as you showed me in chat does put backslash tokens (with catcode other, I am sure) in the list. I wanted control sequences, however …

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It appears, however, that I also get BAD tokens in lualatex if I include `"\\\\"`, which is what I originally wanted to do. And that makes no sense, as `\\ ` is known to latex. (I'll experiment some more.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen you might need to ask Hans... (I couldn't get it to work)

Comment: Okay, I might. But now I have to go solve the original problem by moving it out of the lua realm into latex.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment.

It is unlikely that this will be made working, see this comment in the source of [`lnewtokenlib.c`](https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/blob/c1909e4a4c5311197a253708614af973d9a6f989/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/lua/lnewtokenlib.c#L1277-L1279):

> this is a relating simple converter; if more is needed one can just use tex.print with a regular \def or \gdef and feed the string into the regular scanner;

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that approach did occur to me last night. One could wish there were some warnings in the manual, though.