# tilde ~ in lua adds a new line

Tags: luatex

I am setting a macro in lualatex, and would like to use `~` as a non-breaking space character. However, it produces a new line between first and last.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
    Note tilde is fine in luacode*.\\
    \begin{luacode*}
        token.set_macro('NAME','First~Last','global')
    \end{luacode*}
    \NAME
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not supported by `token.set_macro`. Just use something along the lines of `tex.sprint("\\gdef\\NAME{First~Last}")`.

Answer (score 4):

This is possibly a luatex feature...

If I use plain text and `\directlua` primitive to avoid any interference from macro packages then

```
   \directlua{
        token.set_macro('NAME','First\string~Last','global')
}
\show    \NAME


\def\zz#1{\show#1\ifx!#1\else\expandafter\zz\fi}

\expandafter\zz\NAME!

\bye
```

where the `\show\NAME`  shows `~1` instead of just `~` where the `~1` produces a line break.

```
> \NAME=macro:
->First~1Last.
l.6 \show    \NAME
```

The loop then shows each token and you get:

```
> the letter F.
> the letter i.
> the letter r.
> the letter s.
> the letter t.
> [unknown command code! (13, -1113986)].
> the letter L.
> the letter a.
> the letter s.
> the letter t.
```

So basically the token library hasn't wanted to add the active character.

Comment: See  Marcel's comment here https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59327212#59327212 I think basically this isn't supported you need to add `\nobreak\space` rather than the active `~` or in latex use `\nobreakspace`

Comment: I would even call this a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519954/backslashes-in-macros-defined-in-lua-code. See in particular [my “answer”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519991) over there.