# How to pass the the content from Lua function to a LaTeX3 token list (tl)?

Tags: latex3, lua, token-lists

I have a Lua function that generates LaTeX content (a string containing LaTeX commands like `"\\textbf{foo}"`) and it can be successfully outputted with `\lua_now:n` and `tex.print()`. Now I'm planning to record the content for the purpose of `l3build` regression test and I try to pass the content to a token list and then write it the log file with `\tl_show:N`. However the following code raises an error: `Illegal parameter number in definition of \l__csl_bibliography_tl`. Is there another approach?

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
function make_bibliography()
  local result = "\\textbf{Foo}"
  tex.print(result)
end
\end{luacode*}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__csl_bibliography_tl
\cs_new:Npn \printbibliography
  {
    % \lua_now:n { make_bibliography() }   % It works fine.
    \tl_set:Nx \l__csl_bibliography_tl { \lua_now:n { make_bibliography() } }
    \tl_show:N \l__csl_bibliography_tl
    \tl_use:N \l__csl_bibliography_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the tl (macro) from Lua:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
function make_bibliography()
  local result = "\\textbf{Foo}"
  token.set_macro("l__csl_bibliography_tl",result)
end
\end{luacode*}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__csl_bibliography_tl
\cs_new:Npn \printbibliography
  {
    \lua_now:n{ make_bibliography() }
    \tl_show:N \l__csl_bibliography_tl
    \tl_use:N \l__csl_bibliography_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Note that `token.set_macro` does not handle the case where result contains e.g. a `~` character and the catcode of `~` is currently active.

Also any control sequences used (eg `\textbf` here)  must already be in the hash table.  See [tilde ~ in lua adds a new line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618254/tilde-in-lua-adds-a-new-line/618256#618256) for some discussion of this.

Comment: Note that `token.set_macro` does not handle the case where `result` contains e.g. a `~` character and the catcode of `~` is currently active correctly, as well as the case where some control sequence is in the string but not in the hash table. → [luatex - tilde ~ in lua adds a new line - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618254/tilde-in-lua-adds-a-new-line/618256#618256) & linked questions from there.

Comment: @user202729 yes, I stole your comment and added to my answer, thanks

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `\textbf` doesn't survive `x`-expansion. You can wrap the problematic construction with `\text_expand:n`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
function make_bibliography()
  local result = "\\textbf{Foo}"
  tex.print(result)
end
\end{luacode*}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__csl_bibliography_tl
\cs_new:Npn \printbibliography
  {
    \tl_set:Nx \l__csl_bibliography_tl { \text_expand:n { \lua_now:n { make_bibliography() } } }
    \tl_show:N \l__csl_bibliography_tl
    \tl_use:N \l__csl_bibliography_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

In the console you'll see

```
> \l__csl_bibliography_tl=\textbf {Foo}.
```

and the output is

[image]

Comment: I think Carlisle's approach is simpler because it involves less expansion control. Thank you all the same.

Comment: @ZepingLee But it assumes that token lists variables are implemented as macros (which is true up to some point).