# Understanding some pieces of luatex the program

Tags: luatex

[I'm looking forward](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=682) the implementation of a [`tex.execute()`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20893/concurrently-interleaving-execution-of-lua-and-tex-in-luatex) command on the `lua` side in luatex. But it needs patching `luatex` the program and I have a dream: providing the patch... :)

As I have nearly no experience with dealing with such big projects with lots of libraries entangled, I'd like to be taught how to read a piece of `luatex` code and understand it.

I have three examples in mind:

1. the `\directlua` primitive (to understand the tex2lua route);
2. the `tex.sprint` function (to understand the lua2tex route);
3. the `tex.getbox` function (to understand how `lua` interact with `TeX` material).

Note: when travelling for summer holidays, I can understand people speaking `C` provided they speak slowly but I'm a bit too shy to speak myself :)

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here

Comment: @JosephWright Ok, I'll edit to try to be more specific.

Comment: If you plan to provide a patch to luatex, it is essential to read the Luatex manual (which assumes that you already understand the TeXBook).

Comment: Any news on this here? Should we close it or do you plan to provide some details?

Comment: @PatrickGundlach Let's close it. I'll try again in the future.