# How to new a box in lua with luatex/lualatex?

Tags: luatex, box

I want to set a box register so I use `\setbox180=\hbox{TEST}`
under the function `tex.print` and then use
`directlua` to get its width. So This programme:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\directlua{
    function w(obj)
        if obj == nil then
            return "nil"
        else
            return obj.width
        end
    end
}

I make three box that have widthes in%
\setbox200=\hbox{TEST AND TEST}%
\directlua{
    tex.print("\string\\setbox180=\string\\hbox{AB}")
    tex.print(w(tex.box[180]).." sp and "..w(tex.box[200]).."sp")
}.

I make two box that have widthes in
\directlua{
    tex.print(w(tex.box[180]).." sp and "..w(tex.box[200]).."sp")
}.

\end{document}
```

But the output is:

```
I make three box that have widthes in nil sp and 5434245sp.
I make two box that have widthes in 955515 sp and 5434245sp.
```

that means that the box in the `directlua` cannot be made in time
but after when it exits the command.

How can I make it? Is there other ways to assign the box register?

Thank you a lot.

(I edit it to make it run. [Concurrently interleaving execution of Lua and TeX in LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20893/concurrently-interleaving-execution-of-lua-and-tex-in-luatex) looks have the answer that I want)

Comment: `\luaderict` looks like a typo. Does your code actually run?

Comment: please always provide a test document that show the error, your text says `\luadirect`  your code says `\luaderict` but neither of those commands are defined by default in lualatex.

Comment: Thanks for your help~ `>_<`