# Lua function returning a list of values to TikZ foreach loop

Tags: luatex, loops, luacode

I was trying to come up with a Lua-based solution to another question here and failed miserably. There something I certainly don't understand about LuaLaTeX. Here is a toy code that shows the problem.

The Lua function receives an integer that must be 1 or 2 and, depending on this value, will return (through `tex.print`) a different subdivision of interval [0,3]. The returned string is received by a `foreach` loop, hopefully to use it as a list of abscissas for a graph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}

\LuaCodeDebugOn
\begin{luacode}
function listx(n)
    local values = ""
    if n == 1 then
        for i=1, 3 do
            values = values .. i .. ","
        end
    elseif n == 2 then
        for i=1, 6 do
            values = values .. i/2 .. ","
        end
    end
    values = values:sub(1, -2)
    tex.print(values)
end
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\directlua{listx(2)}  % displays 0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {\directlua{listx(2)}} { 
    \fill (\x,0.5) circle (0.02);
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The first line after `\begin{document}` shows that the function prints the expected list of values, just as a test.

But the TikZ picture shows a single dot at coordinates (0,0), instead of 3 or 6 dots evenly spaced. My guess is that, for some reason, `tex.print` doesn't send the data in the proper format for `foreach`, or that some LaTeX processing happens too soon, or too late...

I'm surprised because I routinely use Lua code to compute numerical values that I pass to `siunitx` for good rendering. I assume the problem comes from the fact that I'm trying to pass a *list* of values from Lua to LaTeX, something that I had never tried to do before.

In any case, I'm a bit out of my league, and I don't seem to be able to make `\LuaCodeDebugOn` show any code to help me understand what's happening.

How must I call the Lua function, how must it send its result back, so that `foreach` understands it as a list of numbers to loop over?

(please don't pay too much attention to the Lua code itself, it's just a stupid toy program I wrote for this post)

Comment: [TikZ \foreach loop with macro-defined list - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12091/tikz-foreach-loop-with-macro-defined-list) (also special case 3 of my answer in [verbatim - Why can't I use <some macro> inside the argument of <some other macro>? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645995/why-cant-i-use-some-macro-inside-the-argument-of-some-other-macro), read if you're interested)

Comment: Thank you for the link, however the solution suggested in it doesn't seem to work here. I removed the braces around the `\directlua` macro and now get a "Missing number, treated as zero." near this macro. Is it something specific to `\directlua`'s behavior?

Comment: See the comment I just added to that question (I can't find an existing question that covers it though.)

Comment: Thank you, I'll read it in detail in the morning. However it doesn't seem to be a Lua-based solution, which defeats the purpose of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More recent versions of `tikz` support the `expand list` option for `\foreach`:

```
\foreach[expand list] \x in {\directlua{listx(2)}} {  % <--- changed
    \fill (\x,0.5) circle (0.02);
};
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}

\LuaCodeDebugOn
\begin{luacode}
function listx(n)
    local values = ""
    if n == 1 then
        for i=1, 3 do
            values = values .. i .. ","
        end
    elseif n == 2 then
        for i=1, 6 do
            values = values .. i/2 .. ","
        end
    end
    values = values:sub(1, -2)
    tex.print(values)
end
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\directlua{listx(2)}  % displays 0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach[expand list] \x in {\directlua{listx(2)}} {  % <--- changed
    \fill (\x,0.5) circle (0.02);
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was hoping to be able to use as a syntax! It works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's particularly "bad" to use `edef`, but this is a "pure Lua" solution:

<sub>nevertheless not everything can be done in pure Lua, if you want some TeX programming you need to switch to TeX sometimes, see [Concurrently interleaving execution of Lua and TeX in LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20893/250119)</sub>

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}

\LuaCodeDebugOn
\begin{luacode*}
function foreachlistx(n)
    local values = ""
    if n == 1 then
        for i=1, 3 do
            values = values .. i .. ","
        end
    elseif n == 2 then
        for i=1, 6 do
            values = values .. i/2 .. ","
        end
    end
    values = values:sub(1, -2)
    tex.print([[\foreach \x in {]] .. values .. "}")
end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\directlua{foreachlistx(2)} {
    \fill (\x,0.5) circle (0.02);
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course the solution could be improved a bit by e.g. splitting the value list computation to a separate Lua function that can be called independently, but as I mentioned previously `\foreach` does not expand its argument in braces there isn't really a cleaner way. What it does should be relatively easy to understand (`\directlua{...}` "expands" <sup>(*)</sup> to `\foreach \x in {...}`, which is followed by the code to be executed, which as you can see does what you want)

(*): from LuaTeX manual

> Note that the expansion of \directlua is a sequence of characters, not of tokens, contrary to all
> TEX commands. So formally speaking its expansion is null, but it places material on a pseudo-file
> to be immediately read by TEX, as -TEX’s \scantokens.

Comment: Thanks again, for the code and also for the links. I'm currently trying to see how far I can push Lua in LaTeX, and at this point I need a better understanding of their interaction. This will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can speak:

```tex
\edef\mylist{\directlua{listx(2)}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x  in \mylist { 
    \fill (\x,0.5) circle (0.1);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

or

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\begin{tikzpicture}
\exp_args:Nx\clist_map_inline:nn{\directlua{listx(2)}}
{
  \fill (#1,0.5) circle(0.1);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\ExplSyntaxOn
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It does work, however I lose the ability to pass 1 or 2 as an argument. I read a bit about `\edef` and it doesn't seem to be possible to make it accept arguments without quite a bit of tweaking.

Comment: @Miyase What do you mean "pass argument"? You're passing 2 there

Comment: But that 2 is hard-coded in the `\mylist` macro, so I can't change it when I call the macro in the loop.

Comment: @Miyase Yes you can, just put the whole edef inside the loop.

Comment: OK, I'll try that. Thanks again.